# Images from ipad not rotating properly

Tags: media

I have noticed that users who upload their images from iPad or iPhone have their images sometimes rotated in odd directions. I am not a Drupal guru and I generally find that documentation on drupal "how to" is ..well.. scarce,,

I have spent some time looking into this and did not find anything that would effectively help me.

What I would like to accomplish seems simple in principle but I need help.

Rather then forcing users to rotate images *(they find that to be clunky and awkward I have an average user who is interested solely to have things happen simply and without hassle)* I would like to have ALL my images on the site checked for orientation and have them automatically display the images in proper orientation.

I came across a module called [Imagecache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) and it is supposed to have Autorotate capability but I have no clue on how to use it for what I need.

ALL help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The -auto-orient operator is part of the ImageMagick image processing toolkit, to select the correct orientation of an image based on its EXIF data. Have a look at [How to detect shot angle of photo ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657023/how-to-detect-shot-angle-of-photo-and-auto-rotate-for-website-display-like-desk) for a more complete explanation.

The [ImageMagick](https://drupal.org/project/imagemagick) module integrates this function in Drupal, but they are still having an [issue](https://drupal.org/node/1964064) with autorotation. A recent patch is available there.

Your best bet is to try it out and see if it corrects your problem.

Comment: I am getting errors
Warning: Division by zero in theme_image_style_preview()
(which is better then not getting anything)

Comment: I can't use imagemagick (server side limitatons). ImageCache Autorotate does rotate non apple device images Apple device images do not contain exif information so Autorotate does not work.